# How to obtain a dump of the Mozilla Developer Network site

Tags: download, wget, mozilla, dump

What size is the entire Mozilla Developer Network site? `api.jquery.com` is about 40MB when downloaded via `wget`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per [bugzilla bug 757461](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=757461) and the [download section at the About page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/About#Downloading_content), MDN provides weekly snapshots of the entire site content available at:

(Updated link, but the content is old until [this issue](https://github.com/mozmeao/infra/issues/600) is fixed.)

https://mdn-downloads.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/developer.mozilla.org.tar.gz

It's approximately 8GB for the content.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/media/developer.mozilla.org.tar.gz is a dead link  :(

Comment: Oops, new link is https://mdn-downloads.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/developer.mozilla.org.tar.gz thought the content is still old. I'll update the answer.