# Database of all Javascript Objects and Methods Typed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, documentation

I am looking for a database referencing all objects and methods Javascript with a typing and optionally descriptions, as we can find on VSCode.
I am currently working on an IDE and my API (autocompletion and others ...) must have access to the detailed properties of each object
Thanks you

Comment: I never so one as complete as you are asking for, mostly because of weak typing, JavaScript do not bother much about type.

Comment: In fact, Javascript recognizes several instances of classes like Number, String, Array etc.

Comment: Looks like a good starter, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909114/how-to-obtain-a-dump-of-the-mozilla-developer-network-site

Comment: [Chr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8535049/chr), I am not saying that it has no types, I'm saying it do not bother much, if you create a variable that is a number you can eventually set it to string or even array or other object. Besides, must types in JavaScript are objects, except for primitives, but even they have objects linked to then, such as Number and String.

Comment: If I have to do this library myself it may take some time ... But I would do it if it does not exist. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I have created a package referencing all JavaScript properties in Json format with some processing functions

https://github.com/log4b0at/jsreferencer-env-js

Anyone can participate to fill this documentation :)